# I really want to know what is proper the cpu temperature for my Mac book

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cpu, temperature

I'm using Mac book pro 13 inch , 3.1 ghz i5 dual core.

I have set up Mac book fan control and I am able to check the temperature.

I was just surfing the internet, and the cpu temperature shows about 65-75 degree Celsius. which made the fan run

Is it normal thing to happen???

I cannot find any proper temperature for my Mac.

I also looked up at some website but it does not have my MacBook model.

https://www.intelmactemp.com/list

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two **13" MacBook Pro** notebooks which offered a **3.1 GHz i5 CPU** with **2** *physical cores*. Both have a **100°C**  **T**<sub>**JUNCTION**</sub> rating for the **CPU**. (Junction Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die.):

- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP748?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

  - Model Identifier - MacBookPro13,2
  - [Intel® Core™ i5-6287U Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91164/intel-core-i5-6287u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html)
  - T<sub>JUNCTION</sub>  100°C
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP755?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

  - Model Identifier - MacBookPro14,2
  - [Intel® Core™ i5-7287U Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97531/intel-core-i5-7287u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz.html)
  - T<sub>JUNCTION</sub>  100°C

So a temperature of **65-75°C** is within normal operating range for the **CPU**.

If neither of these are the **MacBook Pro** model you have, then please provide the necessary information to properly identify the one you have.

Comment: I think mine is the one with 2017.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I was seriously concerning about it.